# How to do the integration: $\int x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

More general, how to integrate:
$\int x^n\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx$

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 3):

Setting $x=a\sin\theta$, we get (assuming $a>0$)
$$ \int x^n\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\;dx=\int (a\sin\theta)^na\cos\theta\sqrt{a^2(1-\sin^2\theta)}\;d\theta$$
$$ =a^{n+2}\int\sin^n\theta\cos^2\theta\;d\theta $$
This integral can be handled either using trig identities or integration by parts, though both methods will be tedious for large $n$. Once this is done, one must then use $x=a\sin\theta$ and some trig to switch back to $x$.

Comment: +1 While it's correct, I think it would be better to clarify that since the integrand is defined for $x\in[-a,a]$, the change of variable $x=a\sin \theta$ occurs (for instance) for $\theta\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, hence $\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}=|\cos\theta|$ but $\cos\theta$ is actually positive and the absolute value is not necessary. For the sake of the unconscious reader :) This looks like nitpicking, but trig integrals (and trigonometry in general) often lead to absolute values that cause many sign mistakes or worse.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: good point, thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

By changing variable. Let $x=a\cos u$ then $dx=-a\sin u du$ by replacing to $x$ you will get:
$$\int a^2\cos^2 u (a\sin u)(-a\sin u du)$$
Then you can solve as a trigonometric integral.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $$I_n=\int x^n\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\,dx$$ it seems natural to change variable $x=a \sin(y)$ which makes $$I_n=a^{n+2}\int\cos ^2(y) \sin ^n(y)\,dy$$ Now, we can simplify it to $$I_n=a^{n+2}\left(\int\sin ^n(y)\,dy-\int\sin ^{n+2}(y)\,dy\right)$$ which are quite standard and easy to compute by reduction (have a look [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~richard/Math230/reduction.pdf)).

So, if you consider (as given in the link) that $$J_n=\int \sin^n(y)\,dy=-\frac{1}{n}\cos (y) \sin ^{n-1}(y)+\frac{n-1}n J_{n-2}$$ you should end with $$I_n=a^{n+2}\left(\cos (y) \sin ^{n-1}(y) \left(\frac{\sin ^2(y)}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{n-1}n J_{n-2}-\frac{n+1}{n+2} J_{n}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts... choose $u=x^{n-1}$ and $dv=\sqrt{a^2-x^2}xdx$ then you have $du=(n-1)x^{n-2}dx$ and $v=-\frac{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}$ thus:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int{x^n\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx}&=&(x^{n-1})\left(-\frac{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}\right)-\int{-\frac{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}}(n-1)x^{n-2}dx\\
&=&-\left(\frac{(x^{n-1})(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}\right)+\frac{(n-1)}{3}\int{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}x^{n-2}dx
\end{eqnarray}

Now, you choose $u=x^{n-3}$ and $dv=(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}xdx$ and repeat the process as much as $n$ admit.

For $n=2$ you will have:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int{x^2\sqrt{a^2-x^2}dx}&=&-\left(\frac{(x)(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}{3}\right)+\frac{1}{3}\int{(a^2-x^2)^{3/2}}dx
\end{eqnarray}

The last integral it solves by trigonometric substitution, Have fun :).